# Creating a loop script

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I have a script that notifies users every minute. I set an array of users for each minute.
I would like to create a script that limits the number of users for one minute and passes a user along to the next minute when the array is full.
I can create it stepwise like this (just a sample scheme of my script):

```js
let min = 1
if (min.users.length > 10) {
let nextmin = min + 1
if (nextmin.users.length > 10) {
let nextnextmin = nextmin + 1
if (nextnextmin.users.length > 10) {
.....
} else {
// setting user for the next next min
}
} else {
// setting user for the next min
}
} else {
// setting user for the min
}
```

What I need is the script that checks on the next minute in a loop until it finds an array with a number of users under the set limit.

Comment: setTimeout or setInterval

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know how to make it run every minute, I need it to check the array of users for the next minute until it finds one with fewer users than the limit.

Comment: setTimeout + setInterval then.  clearInterval after 1 minute, or whatver it is, and set a new interval

Comment: Thanks, but it's not what I was asking for.
Let's say the max users for a minute are 10
A user sets the notification time for 12:00
Let's imagine the data look like this:
12:00 set for 10 users
12:01 set for 10 users
12:02 set for 5 users
I need the script to check on 12:00, 12:01 until it finds 12:02 cause there are fewer users than 10
I hope I made it clear now :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm understanding your question correctly. Try the code below.

```
//usersArray = array that holds arrays of users per minute, maxUsers = limit of users per minute
function numUsersPerMin(usersArray,maxUsers){
    for(let i = 0; i<userArray[i].length; i++) {
        if(userArray[i].length < maxUsers){
            return i; //I'm not sure what you want returned so I'm just returning the
                      //index of where the first array that is below maxUsers is
        }    
        
    }
}
//i acts as the "minute"
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you, I'll try it out!